# Start nvim with a bindsym in i3

Tags: manjaro, i3, rxvt, nvim

How can can I start nvim with a bindsym from i3? If I just type

```
bindsym $mod+F1 exec nvim
```

nvim doesn't show, since it just runs in the background without a terminal. So how can I invoke nvim with a keybind in i3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as Manjaro and rxvt, I'm supposing that the terminal emulator you're using is [rxvt-unicode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode). In this case, you can use:

```
bindsym $mod+F1 exec --no-startup-id urxvt -e nvim
```

Even if you use a different terminal, most emulators have a similar option to execute a command on startup.